# I wanna fill my filtered data with repeated sequence of numbers like from 1 to 4 then again 1 to 4 in filtered data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanna fill my filtered data with repeated sequence of numbers like from 1 to 4 then again 1 to 4 in filtered data.

I don't have an idea.

[image]

In Column D I wanna repeat numbers agin and again. Need support

Answer (score 1):

If there are no empty values:

```
=MOD(SUBTOTAL(3,$A$2:A2)-1,4)+1
```

And drag it down. Result:

[image]

Comment: Superb. Working 1000%. Thank you very much.